# Is StringEncoder splitting an extremely long string randomly?

Tags: java, netty

I am attempting to send some JSON string with a RCS Public Key in it with GSON. Whenever the string gets transferred to the client, it gets split.

Currently I only have these encoders (They are basically string encoders with some extra functionality)

Do I require any extra encoders or decoders that will join the string together or do I need to code it manually? If I do, any explanation on how to do it?

An example of what a JSON string would look like is this: https://pastebin.com/UkDGKHya
The public key is unique and generated every time the packet is sent, though it's only sent once for registering the client.

Server:

```java
                        ch.pipeline().addLast("stringDecoder", new EncryptedGSONObjectDecoder(CharsetUtil.UTF_8, keyFinder));

                        ch.pipeline().addLast("stringEncoder", new EncryptedGSONObjectEncoder(CharsetUtil.UTF_8, keyFinder));

                        ch.pipeline().addLast(processingHandler);
```

Client:

```java
                    ch.pipeline().addLast("readTimeoutHandler", new ReadTimeoutHandler(15));

                    ch.pipeline().addLast("stringDecoder",new EncryptedGSONObjectDecoder(CharsetUtil.UTF_8, Client.this));

                    ch.pipeline().addLast("stringEncoder", new EncryptedGSONObjectEncoder(CharsetUtil.UTF_8, Client.this));

                    ch.pipeline().addLast(clientHandler);
```

Comment: You have to be aware that string decoder has undefined behaviour when used without a "framing" handler before it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had to add a LineBasedFrameDecoder and add "\n\r" at the end of the string when encoding